# Bcrypted password as env variable in the helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there any way to store bcrypted password in the helm chart environmental variable as something like:

```
service:
  environment:
     - PASSWORD="{bcrypt}$2a$04$WQsYXSBcO1/7E9bevWX3.Gxv2V6ZfYx93lm9.4Tje"
```

When I have run helm chart with that value it was complaining that

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "service": "PASSWORD="{bcrypt}$2a$04$WQsYXSBcO1/7E9bevWX3.Gxv2V6ZfYx93lm9.4Tje""
```

Comment: It sounds like more a Docker Compose question than Helm, no ?

Comment: @LoganMzz I'm trying to get that to work with the helm chart nothing to do with the `docker-compose`

Comment: Strange because it's a Docker Compose error message :/ See https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/config/interpolation.py#L53
Otherwise, I see no issue: https://gist.github.com/loganmzz/0311ac84e7e8a1e0dd55c1eff1ac0f5f